# JoinAcross Crashes Kernel in Version 11.0

Tags: bugs, dataset, associations

**Bug introduced in 11.0.0 and fixed in 11.0.1**

---

The following executes without issue in 10.4.1 and returns immediately.  However in 11.0 when the `JoinAcross` line is executed all available system memory is immediately consumed and after a long while the kernel crashes.

```
dates = Transpose[{ConstantArray[First@# , Length@Last@#], Last@#, 
         RandomInteger[{20, 100}, Length@Last@#]}] &@
      {#, DateRange[#, {2016, 6}, "Quarter"]} & /@
     DateRange[{1994, 3}, {2016, 6}, "Quarter"] //
   Flatten[#, 1] &;

dsDetail = 
  AssociationThread[{"InitialDate", "AccountingDate", "Value"}, #] & /@
     dates // Dataset;

dsSummary = AssociationThread[{"AccountingDate", "Value"}, #] & /@
    With[{d = DateRange[{1994, 3}, {2016, 6}, "Quarter"]}, 
     Transpose@{d, RandomInteger[{100, 200}, Length@d]}] //
   Dataset;
```

This next line will run fine in 10.4.1 but will consume all available system memory and crash the kernel in 11.0.  The OS is very unresponsive while this is executing in 11.0 so I would advise you have all your *Mathematica* work saved and closed as a precaution.

```
JoinAcross[dsDetail, dsSummary, "AccountingDate", 
 KeyCollisionFunction -> ({"Detail" <> #, "Summary" <> #} &)]
```

It is a bug, correct?
Version 11.0 Win 7 Ent SP1

**Bug:** [CASE:3694291]

Comment: On OS X it hangs, but I didn't wait for a crash. (I.e. yes I see a problem too.)  You reported this to support, right?

Comment: @Szabolcs Will now.  Wanted to confirm.

Comment: On my MacOS X 10.10, Mathematica 10.3.1, `dsDetail//AtomQ` and `dsSummary//AtomQ` both yield `True`.  On Mathematica 11, they yield `False`, so the final `JoinAcross` command doesn't work.  Actually, on my computer (v11) `Dataset` doesn't even create the `Dataset` object... something is wrong.

Comment: @QuantumDot Using `Normal` on the `Dataset`s in `JoinAcross` still results in the same behavior.  After your comment I would have thought that this change would work since it drops the `Dataset` into its list of `Association`s. However there was no joy to be found.

Comment: V11.0.0 fails and V10.4 works on Linux.  It appears that it uses increasing amounts of memory (more than 50GB) before I stopped it.  You can wrap the calculation in `MemoryConstrained` if you don't actually want to see it crash.

Answer (score 5):

This bug has been fixed in the just released Mathematica 11.0.1.

[image]