# How do I 'Join' two Structured Datasets?

Tags: programming, dataset

Consider the following Datasets

```
dsCompetitions with fields {"id","name","eventTypeId"}

dsEventTypes with fields {"id", "name"}
```

I want to join the datasets as follows using SQL pseudocode:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, e.name
FROM dsCompetions c, dsEventTypes e
WHERE c.eventTypeId = e.id;
```

Resulting in a

```
Dataset with fields {"id", "name", "eventtype"}
```

I read the document about Datasets (JoinAcross) and tried JoinAcross but with no success.

See also: [JoinAcross Crashes Kernel in Version 11.0](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124520/joinacross-crashes-kernel-in-version-11-0)

***BEGIN TEST DATA ( USE COPY / PASTE TO NOTEBOOK )***

dsEventTypes1 = 
 Dataset[{<|"id" -> 1, "name" -> "Soccer"|>, <|"id" -> 2, 
    "name" -> "Tennis"|>, <|"id" -> 3, 
    "name" -> "Golf"|>, <|"id" -> 4, 
    "name" -> "Cricket"|>, <|"id" -> 5, 
    "name" -> "Rugby Union"|>, <|"id" -> 1477, 
    "name" -> "Rugby League"|>, <|"id" -> 6, 
    "name" -> "Boxing"|>, <|"id" -> 7, 
    "name" -> "Horse Racing"|>, <|"id" -> 8, 
    "name" -> "Motor Sport"|>, <|"id" -> 27454571, 
    "name" -> "E-Sports"|>, <|"id" -> 998918, 
    "name" -> "Bowls"|>, <|"id" -> 10, 
    "name" -> "Special Bets"|>, <|"id" -> 998917, 
    "name" -> "Volleyball"|>, <|"id" -> 11, 
    "name" -> "Cycling"|>, <|"id" -> 136332, 
    "name" -> "Chess"|>, <|"id" -> 315220, 
    "name" -> "Poker"|>, <|"id" -> 3988, 
    "name" -> "Athletics"|>, <|"id" -> 6422, 
    "name" -> "Snooker"|>, <|"id" -> 6231, 
    "name" -> "Financial Bets"|>, <|"id" -> 6423, 
    "name" -> "American Football"|>, <|"id" -> 7511, 
    "name" -> "Baseball"|>, <|"id" -> 27829360, 
    "name" -> "MMA / UFC"|>, <|"id" -> 606611, 
    "name" -> "Netball"|>, <|"id" -> 451485, 
    "name" -> "Winter Sports"|>, <|"id" -> 7522, 
    "name" -> "Basketball"|>, <|"id" -> 7524, 
    "name" -> "Ice Hockey"|>, <|"id" -> 61420, 
    "name" -> "Australian Rules"|>, <|"id" -> 468328, 
    "name" -> "Handball"|>, <|"id" -> 3503, 
    "name" -> "Darts"|>, <|"id" -> 4339, 
    "name" -> "Greyhound Racing"|>, <|"id" -> 2378961, 
    "name" -> "Politics"|>, <|"id" -> 72382, "name" -> "Pool"|>}]

dsCompetitions1 = 
 Dataset[{<|"id" -> 4515398, "name" -> "T&T Pro League", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 7, 
    "name" -> "Austrian Bundesliga", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 9, "name" -> "Erste Liga", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 11, "name" -> "Dutch Jupiler League", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 13, "name" -> "Campeonato", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 15, "name" -> "Bulgarian Premier",
     "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 17, 
    "name" -> "Croatian Division 1", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 4431442, "name" -> "Algerian Ligue 1", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 1587980, 
    "name" -> "Lithuanian 1 Lyga", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 4732508, "name" -> "Uzbekistan Youth League U23", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 21, "name" -> "Synot Liga", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 23, "name" -> "Danish Superliga", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 8580762, 
    "name" -> "Liga Bet - South B", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 25, "name" -> "Danish Division 1", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 821269, "name" -> "Tercera Division", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 9404054, 
    "name" -> "Dutch Eredivisie", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 872215, "name" -> "Ukrainian Persha Liga", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 7511144, 
    "name" -> "Argentinian Primera C Metropolitana", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 7946082, 
    "name" -> "Ukrainian U21 League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 842258, "name" -> "Qatari Stars League", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 31, 
    "name" -> "English Premier League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 35, "name" -> "League One", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 6480193, "name" -> "Nicaraguan Premier Division", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 321319, 
    "name" -> "Brazilian Division 2", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 37, "name" -> "League Two", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 868392, "name" -> "Russian Youth League", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 8244827, 
    "name" -> "Denmark Series", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 39, 
    "name" -> "National League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 8594603, "name" -> "Peruvian Primera Division", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 4905, "name" -> "Liga 1", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 1065530, 
    "name" -> "Venezuelan Primera", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 6908995, "name" -> "Kuwait Premier League", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 2609677, 
    "name" -> "Moroccan Division 1", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 4655, "name" -> "Copa Sudamericana", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 4556663, 
    "name" -> "Algerian U21 Ligue 2", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 7809093, "name" -> "Primera B Metropolitana (Res)", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 4556656, 
    "name" -> "Algerian Ligue 2", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 879931, "name" -> "Chinese Super League", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 55, "name" -> "French Ligue 1", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 4517491, "name" -> "I Divizion", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 57, "name" -> "French Ligue 2", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 67387, 
    "name" -> "Argentinian Primera Division", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 59, "name" -> "Bundesliga 1", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 10150305, "name" -> "A League 2016/17", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 10222240, 
    "name" -> "Sergipano A2", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 61, 
    "name" -> "Bundesliga 2", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 65, 
    "name" -> "Regionalliga Sudwest", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 175680, "name" -> "Turkish Division 1", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 67, 
    "name" -> "Greek Super League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 961354, "name" -> "Chilean Cup", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 880458, "name" -> "Russian Division 1", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 3792498, 
    "name" -> "Algerian U21 Ligue 1", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 77, "name" -> "Airtricity Premier Division", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 81, "name" -> "Serie A", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 83, "name" -> "Serie B", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 8770515, 
    "name" -> "Mexican Liga Premier", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 2134, "name" -> "EFL Cup", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 89, "name" -> "J League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 164952, "name" -> "Belgian Second Division", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 9161936, 
    "name" -> "Kyrgyzstan Top Liga", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 862545, "name" -> "Estonian Meistriliiga", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 833616, 
    "name" -> "Greek Football League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 93, "name" -> "Tippeligaen", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 30558, "name" -> "English FA Cup", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 6569531, "name" -> "Cymru Alliance", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 97, "name" -> "Ekstraklasa", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 99, "name" -> "Primeira Liga", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 4095837, "name" -> "Moroccan Cup",
     "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 840808, 
    "name" -> "Regionalliga West", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 101, "name" -> "Premier Division", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 803690, "name" -> "Ecuadorian Primera A", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 827754, 
    "name" -> "Mexican Liga de Ascenso", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 103, "name" -> "Serbian Super Liga", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 105, 
    "name" -> "Scottish Premiership", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 8771055, "name" -> "El Salvador U20 League", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 107, 
    "name" -> "Scottish Championship", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 7247362, "name" -> "Ugandan Premier League", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 7317506, 
    "name" -> "Austrian Regionalliga", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 7998231, "name" -> "Danish Division 2", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 109, 
    "name" -> "Scottish League One", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 1227903, "name" -> "Copa Argentina", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 111, 
    "name" -> "Scottish League Two", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 113, "name" -> "Slovakian Super Liga", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 7893771, 
    "name" -> "Copa Venezuela", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 5627174, "name" -> "Mexican Primera Division", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 4684340, 
    "name" -> "Friendlies (W)", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 115, 
    "name" -> "Slovenian Prva Liga", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 9969899, "name" -> "Premier League 2", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 1888360, 
    "name" -> "Ukrainian U19 League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 117, "name" -> "Primera Division", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 119, "name" -> "Segunda Division", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 879221, "name" -> "Lithuanian A Lyga", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 121, "name" -> "Segunda B/1", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 89979, 
    "name" -> "Belgian Jupiler League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 5618479, "name" -> "Israeli Liga Alef", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 123, "name" -> "Segunda B/2", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 8272130, 
    "name" -> "Goa U20 League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 125, 
    "name" -> "Segunda B/3", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 862579, 
    "name" -> "Romanian Liga II", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 1038449, "name" -> "Scottish League Cup", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 20351, 
    "name" -> "NIFL Premiership", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 127,
     "name" -> "Segunda B/4", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 3057583,
     "name" -> "Ecuadorian Primera B", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 129, "name" -> "Allsvenskan", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 2608550, "name" -> "Specials", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 89219, "name" -> "Brazilian Cup", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 131, "name" -> "Superettan", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 318343, "name" -> "Regionalliga Nordost", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 133, 
    "name" -> "Swiss Super League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 252549, "name" -> "Welsh Premier League", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 135, 
    "name" -> "Swiss Challenge League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 887178, "name" -> "Virsliga", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 409743, "name" -> "Scottish Cup", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 139, "name" -> "Vischya Liga", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 403085, "name" -> "Polish 1 Liga", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 1987477, "name" -> "Czech U19 League", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 6251219, 
    "name" -> "Indian Super League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 4596938, "name" -> "Isthmian Division One South", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 141, "name" -> "MLS", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 867459, "name" -> "K League", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 6366702, 
    "name" -> "Shillong Premier League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 1979279, "name" -> "Copa Mexico", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 7616742, "name" -> "Kenyan Premier League", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 194961, 
    "name" -> "CONCACAF Champions League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 876442, "name" -> "Polish 2 Liga", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 1062024, "name" -> "J2 League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 839575, "name" -> "Paraguayan Primera", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 2311356, 
    "name" -> "AFC U19 Championship", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 156320, "name" -> "North American Soccer League", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 4556519, 
    "name" -> "Palestine West Bank League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 862638, "name" -> "Czech 2 Liga", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 194215, "name" -> "Turkish Super League", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 3784863, 
    "name" -> "UEFA Youth League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 844197, "name" -> "Colombian Primera A", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 5984496, "name" -> "Lega Pro", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 4540650, 
    "name" -> "NIFL Reserve League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 853948, "name" -> "Regionalliga Bayern", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 7550146, 
    "name" -> "National Football League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 843454, "name" -> "Uruguayan Primera", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 801976, 
    "name" -> "Egyptian Premier", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 840886, "name" -> "Malaysian Super League", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 3765124, 
    "name" -> "Argentinian Primera B Metropolitana", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 158146, "name" -> "3 Liga", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 804044, 
    "name" -> "Israeli Liga Leumit", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 3006957, "name" -> "Romanian Liga III", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 6182297, 
    "name" -> "Gibraltar Premier Division", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 4644737, 
    "name" -> "Northern Premier League Division One South", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 30921, "name" -> "Danish Cup", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 853446, "name" -> "Saudi Premier",
     "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 848322, 
    "name" -> "Singapore S League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 5614746, "name" -> "FIFA World Cup 2018", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 2005, 
    "name" -> "UEFA Europa League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 4802204, "name" -> "El Salvadoran Primera Division", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 6812603, 
    "name" -> "Guatemalan Primera Division de Ascenso", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 1476085, 
    "name" -> "Malaysian Premier League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 228, "name" -> "UEFA Champions League", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 834025, 
    "name" -> "Spanish Copa Federacion", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 3744990, "name" -> "Copa do Brasil U20", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 258537, 
    "name" -> "UAE Premier League", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 1842928, "name" -> "Hungarian NB I", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 7596190, 
    "name" -> "Croatian 3 HNL", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 7129730, "name" -> "The Championship", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 30961, "name" -> "German Cup", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 3729355, 
    "name" -> "Bolivian Liga Nacional A", "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|
    "id" -> 873203, "name" -> "Estonian Esiliiga", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1|>, <|"id" -> 9554737, 
    "name" -> "ITF Colombia Futures", "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|
    "id" -> 10272700, "name" -> "Barclays ATP World Tour Finals 2016",
     "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|"id" -> 10282617, 
    "name" -> "Santiago Challenger 2016", "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|
    "id" -> 10304603, "name" -> "Tie Break Tens Vienna", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|"id" -> 8479559, 
    "name" -> "Tennis Specials 2016", "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|
    "id" -> 10283675, "name" -> "ITF Suzhou", "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|
    "id" -> 8764909, "name" -> "Fed Cup 2016", "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|
    "id" -> 10282390, "name" -> "If Stockholm Open 2016", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|"id" -> 10284023, 
    "name" -> "ITF Joue-Les-Tours", "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|
    "id" -> 9735288, "name" -> "Wimbledon 2017", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|"id" -> 10282289, 
    "name" -> "European Open 2016", "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|
    "id" -> 10281105, "name" -> "Ningbo Challenger 2016", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|"id" -> 10282705, 
    "name" -> "Las Vegas Challenger 2016", "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|
    "id" -> 8788904, "name" -> "Davis Cup 2016", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|"id" -> 10288748, 
    "name" -> "WTA Tour Finals 2016", "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|
    "id" -> 10281071, "name" -> "VTB Kremlin Cup 2016", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|"id" -> 9556388, 
    "name" -> "French Open 2017", "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|
    "id" -> 10282502, "name" -> "Brest Challenger 2016", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|"id" -> 10094279, 
    "name" -> "US  Open 2017", "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|
    "id" -> 10282051, "name" -> "BNP Paribas Luxembourg Open 2016", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 2|>, <|"id" -> 9884918, "name" -> "US PGA 2017", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 3|>, <|"id" -> 10289644, 
    "name" -> "CIMB Classic 2016", "eventTypeId" -> 3|>, <|
    "id" -> 10272558, "name" -> "Solheim Cup 2017", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 3|>, <|"id" -> 10285407, 
    "name" -> "LPGA BLUE BAY", "eventTypeId" -> 3|>, <|
    "id" -> 10273912, "name" -> "World Cup Of Golf 2016", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 3|>, <|"id" -> 10187164, 
    "name" -> "Ryder Cup 2018", "eventTypeId" -> 3|>, <|
    "id" -> 10292826, "name" -> "Portugal Masters 2016", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 3|>, <|"id" -> 9724204, "name" -> "US Open 2017",
     "eventTypeId" -> 3|>, <|"id" -> 9773869, 
    "name" -> "Open Championship 2017", "eventTypeId" -> 3|>, <|
    "id" -> 9112880, "name" -> "US Masters 2017", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 3|>, <|"id" -> 8597727, 
    "name" -> "Race To Dubai 2016", "eventTypeId" -> 3|>, <|
    "id" -> 10148074, "name" -> "Matador BBQs One Day Cup 2016", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 4|>, <|"id" -> 7126733, 
    "name" -> "ICC Cricket World Cup 2019", "eventTypeId" -> 4|>, <|
    "id" -> 10280907, "name" -> "Test Matches", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 4|>, <|"id" -> 9616981, 
    "name" -> "ICC Champions Trophy 2017", "eventTypeId" -> 4|>, <|
    "id" -> 9962116, "name" -> "One Day Internationals", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 4|>, <|"id" -> 10157220, 
    "name" -> "Big Bash League 2016/17", "eventTypeId" -> 4|>, <|
    "id" -> 9886504, "name" -> "Womens One Day Internationals", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 4|>, <|"id" -> 7713877, 
    "name" -> "Champions Cup 2016/17", "eventTypeId" -> 5|>, <|
    "id" -> 7875241, "name" -> "Aviva Premiership 2016/17", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 5|>, <|"id" -> 8925529, 
    "name" -> "2017 RBS 6 Nations", "eventTypeId" -> 5|>, <|
    "id" -> 9720006, "name" -> "French Top 14 2016/17", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 5|>, <|"id" -> 9969164, 
    "name" -> "National Rugby Championship 2016", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 5|>, <|"id" -> 9717744, 
    "name" -> "European Challenge Cup 2016/17", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 5|>, <|"id" -> 9868559, 
    "name" -> "Currie Cup 2016", "eventTypeId" -> 5|>, <|"id" -> 8921,
     "name" -> "Internationals", "eventTypeId" -> 5|>, <|
    "id" -> 9931418, "name" -> "Mitre 10 Cup 2016", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 5|>, <|"id" -> 8415646, 
    "name" -> "Rugby World Cup 2019", "eventTypeId" -> 5|>, <|
    "id" -> 5496748, "name" -> "Pro12 2016/17", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 5|>, <|"id" -> 10239542, 
    "name" -> "Super League 2017", "eventTypeId" -> 1477|>, <|
    "id" -> 10168263, "name" -> "NRL 2017", "eventTypeId" -> 1477|>, <|
    "id" -> 10188309, "name" -> "State of Origin 2017", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 1477|>, <|"id" -> 215152, 
    "name" -> "November Bouts", "eventTypeId" -> 6|>, <|
    "id" -> 1979414, "name" -> "October Bouts", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 6|>, <|"id" -> 10301629, 
    "name" -> "Speedway Australian GP", "eventTypeId" -> 8|>, <|
    "id" -> 8421842, "name" -> "F1 Outrights 2016", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 8|>, <|"id" -> 8581589, "name" -> "Moto GP 2016",
     "eventTypeId" -> 8|>, <|"id" -> 9084902, 
    "name" -> "Speedway - World Championship 2016", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 8|>, <|"id" -> 10303984, 
    "name" -> "Moto GP Australia", "eventTypeId" -> 8|>, <|
    "id" -> 10275346, "name" -> "F1 United States GP", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 8|>, <|"id" -> 9454110, 
    "name" -> "DOTA The Summit", "eventTypeId" -> 27454571|>, <|
    "id" -> 10096701, "name" -> "Scottish International Open 2016.", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 998918|>, <|"id" -> 8958729, 
    "name" -> "BBC Sports Personality 2016", "eventTypeId" -> 10|>, <|
    "id" -> 8958667, "name" -> "2024 Olympic Host City", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 10|>, <|"id" -> 9476453, 
    "name" -> "Turner Prize 2016", "eventTypeId" -> 10|>, <|
    "id" -> 9927218, "name" -> "Strictly Come Dancing 2016", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 10|>, <|"id" -> 9872462, 
    "name" -> "Man Booker Prize 2016", "eventTypeId" -> 10|>, <|
    "id" -> 10156727, "name" -> "Swedish Idol 2016", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 10|>, <|"id" -> 9927225, 
    "name" -> "The X Factor 2016", "eventTypeId" -> 10|>, <|
    "id" -> 10166523, "name" -> "Italy V SuperLega", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 998917|>, <|"id" -> 10282543, 
    "name" -> "South Korea V V League Women", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 998917|>, <|"id" -> 10282537, 
    "name" -> "South Korea V V League", "eventTypeId" -> 998917|>, <|
    "id" -> 9231083, "name" -> "Poland V Liga Siatkowki", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 998917|>, <|"id" -> 10280116, 
    "name" -> "V FIVB Club World Championships", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 998917|>, <|"id" -> 10280118, 
    "name" -> "V FIVB Club World Championships Women", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 998917|>, <|"id" -> 9734605, 
    "name" -> "UK National Hill Championship", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 11|>, <|"id" -> 9864939, 
    "name" -> "Tour de France 2017", "eventTypeId" -> 11|>, <|
    "id" -> 7008771, 
    "name" -> "New Customer Only. First Bet Exclusive 10", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 136332|>, <|"id" -> 7942963, 
    "name" -> "New Customer Only. first Bet Exclusive 12", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 136332|>, <|"id" -> 6964614, 
    "name" -> "New Customer Only. First Bet Exclusive 8", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 136332|>, <|"id" -> 7942967, 
    "name" -> "New Customer Only. first Bet Exclusive 13", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 136332|>, <|"id" -> 6918343, 
    "name" -> "New Customer Only. First Bet Exclusive 2", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 136332|>, <|"id" -> 6961573, 
    "name" -> "New Customer Only. First Bet Exclusive 4", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 136332|>, <|"id" -> 6694857, 
    "name" -> "New Customer Only. First Bet Exclusive 3", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 136332|>, <|"id" -> 6964600, 
    "name" -> "New Customer Only. First Bet Exclusive 6", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 136332|>, <|"id" -> 7942955, 
    "name" -> "New Customer Only. first Bet Exclusive 14", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 136332|>, <|"id" -> 9135832, 
    "name" -> "2016 World Chess Championships", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 136332|>, <|"id" -> 6964607, 
    "name" -> "New Customer Only. First Bet Exclusive 7", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 136332|>, <|"id" -> 6961599, 
    "name" -> "New Customer Only. First Bet Exclusive 1", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 136332|>, <|"id" -> 7008764, 
    "name" -> "New Customer Only. First Bet Exclusive 9", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 136332|>, <|"id" -> 7942977, 
    "name" -> "New Customer Only. First Bet Exclusive 15", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 136332|>, <|"id" -> 6961588, 
    "name" -> "New Customer Only. First Bet Exclusive 5", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 136332|>, <|"id" -> 9157639, 
    "name" -> "WSOP 2016", "eventTypeId" -> 315220|>, <|
    "id" -> 9993990, "name" -> "Tokyo 2020", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 3988|>, <|"id" -> 9233037, 
    "name" -> "World Championship 2017", "eventTypeId" -> 6422|>, <|
    "id" -> 8707741, "name" -> "The Masters 2017", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 6422|>, <|"id" -> 8568745, 
    "name" -> "UK Championship 2016", "eventTypeId" -> 6422|>, <|
    "id" -> 9964393, "name" -> "Australian Interest Rates", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 6231|>, <|"id" -> 2769078, 
    "name" -> "UK Interest Rates", "eventTypeId" -> 6231|>, <|
    "id" -> 8962390, "name" -> "USA Interest Rates", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 6231|>, <|"id" -> 8788754, "name" -> "CFL 2016", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 6423|>, <|"id" -> 8788798, 
    "name" -> "NCAAF 2016/17", "eventTypeId" -> 6423|>, <|
    "id" -> 8764204, "name" -> "NFL Season 2016/17", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 6423|>, <|"id" -> 6359473, "name" -> "MLB 2016", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7511|>, <|"id" -> 10303773, "name" -> "UFC 207", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 27829360|>, <|"id" -> 10280536, 
    "name" -> "UFC 205", "eventTypeId" -> 27829360|>, <|
    "id" -> 10280610, "name" -> "UFC Fight Night Mexico City", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 27829360|>, <|"id" -> 10169167, 
    "name" -> "Constellation Cup 2016", "eventTypeId" -> 606611|>, <|
    "id" -> 9191429, "name" -> "Alpine Skiing World Cup  2016/17", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 451485|>, <|"id" -> 10220826, 
    "name" -> "Extraliga 2016 - 2017", "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|
    "id" -> 9318860, "name" -> "Liga Endesa", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|"id" -> 9310282, "name" -> "NBA", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|"id" -> 9353227, 
    "name" -> "Dominent Bank Ekstraliga", "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|
    "id" -> 10273173, 
    "name" -> "Bulgarian Basketball League 2016 2017", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|"id" -> 10152915, 
    "name" -> "Japan B1 League", "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|
    "id" -> 9319111, "name" -> "Ligat HaAl", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|"id" -> 10157073, 
    "name" -> "NBA Preseason", "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|
    "id" -> 10139537, "name" -> "Mattoni NBL 2016 - 2017", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|"id" -> 10137367, 
    "name" -> "British Basketball League 2016 - 2017", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|"id" -> 10169429, 
    "name" -> "Basketball League of Serbia 2016 2017", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|"id" -> 10224910, 
    "name" -> "ULEB Eurocup 2016 - 2017", "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|
    "id" -> 10273609, "name" -> "Championnat Pro B 2016- 2016 2017", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|"id" -> 10121859, 
    "name" -> "Championnat Pro A 2016 2017", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|"id" -> 10218496, 
    "name" -> "WNBL 2016 2017", "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|
    "id" -> 10161600, "name" -> "Basketball Champions League", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|"id" -> 10283584, 
    "name" -> "FIBA Europe Cup", "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|
    "id" -> 9317712, "name" -> "Korisliiga", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|"id" -> 10118212, 
    "name" -> "Liga Nacional de Básquetbol 2016 2017", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|"id" -> 9319212, 
    "name" -> "Turkish Airlines Euroleague Basketball", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|"id" -> 9339372, 
    "name" -> "Basketball Bundesliga", "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|
    "id" -> 9338605, "name" -> "WNBA 2016", "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|
    "id" -> 10153726, "name" -> "ABA Liga 2016 - 2017", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|"id" -> 10157361, 
    "name" -> "Australian NBL 2016/17", "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|
    "id" -> 10161710, "name" -> "Canal Digital Ligaen 2016 2017", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|"id" -> 10187180, "name" -> "Ligan", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7522|>, <|"id" -> 8610214, 
    "name" -> "Finland IH Mestis", "eventTypeId" -> 7524|>, <|
    "id" -> 10115932, "name" -> "Sweden IH SHL", 
    "eventTypeId" -> 7524|>}]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provided that your `Datasets` are effectively just a list of `Associations` then you should use [`JoinAcross`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JoinAcross.html), as follows:

```
dsCompetitions = Dataset@{<|"id" -> 1, "name" -> "bob", "eventTypeId" -> 4|>, 
   <|"id" -> 2, "name" -> "frank", "eventTypeId" -> 6|>};
dsEventTypes = Dataset@{<|"id" -> 4, "name" -> "Football"|>, 
   <|"id" -> 5, "name" -> "Baseball"|>, 
   <|"id" -> 6, "name" -> "American Football"|>};

Normal@JoinAcross[dsCompetitions, dsEventTypes, 
   {"eventTypeId" -> "id"}, 
  KeyCollisionFunction -> <|"id" -> {"id", "eventId"}, 
    "name" -> {"compName", "eventName"}|>][All, {"id", "compName", "eventName"}]
(* {<|"id" -> 1, "compName" -> "bob", "eventName" -> "Football"|>, 
  <|"id" -> 2, "compName" -> "frank", "eventName" -> "American Football"|>} *)
```

where `Normal` has been added to simplify the output for SE. The third argument of `JoinAcross` is where you specify the two keys to join. The option [`KeyCollisionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyCollisionFunction.html) specifies which data is to take precedence when there are key collisions among the non-joined fields. But, in this case, it is better to use the function form which provides rewrite rules for the key names to prevent conflicts.

Comment: When I enter the JoinAcross the first occurrence of "Key" colors Red ("An unknown option namehas been used"), although I do get the output. - On ( somewhat ) larger Datasets (300, 25)  I am having problems with this. At the moment anyway.

Comment: Red occurs in Documentation JoinAcross also.

Comment: @niloderoock I see the red, too. I'll take a look at it, and poke the appropriate developers about it.

Comment: @niloderoock What sort of trouble are you having with the large data sets?

Comment: In this example the Output should be
(* {<|"id" -> 4, ""name"-> "Bob", name" -> "Football"|> , etc.*)

Comment: performance issues, I aborted the operation, will try again later.

Comment: If I don't get it to work I'll upload the data I am using. ( Later )

Comment: That sounds like a good plan.

Comment: +1 An alternative that addresses the issues (except performance) from the comments: `JoinAcross[dsCompetitions, dsEventTypes, {"eventTypeId" -> "id"}, 
  KeyCollisionFunction -> <|"id" -> {"id", "eventId"}, 
    "name" -> {"compName", "eventName"}|>][All, {"id", "compName", 
  "eventName"}]`.  Note: it is not possible to have two keys with the same name in an association, so we must disambiguate the two _name_ columns.  Also note that `JoinAcross` does work directly upon datasets.

Comment: @WReach I see, you're using strings directly, not `Key[keyname]`. That would explain the difference. To make it work with lists of `Associations`, too, use `Query` instead, eg. `JoinAcross[...] // Query[All, {"id", "compName", "eventName"}]`.

Comment: @rcollyer I uploaded two datasets. - The suggested solution by WReach works for small datasets but with the ( not so very big 30 / 300 rows ) testdata sets I provided the kernel aborts ( I think ).

Comment: I see the same behaviour (v11.0.0) -- the kernel crashes for the following expression using any valid value for _n_: `JoinAcross[dsCompetitions1[[n;;n+31]],dsEventTypes1,{"eventTypeId"->"id"}]`.  It succeeds if the upper bound is `n+30`, but the memory usage is outrageous (10+ gigabytes).

Comment: Ok, I'll have to think of a workaround for my project.

Comment: @niloderoock on v11.0.1, I can run the full thing without issue. What version are you using?

Comment: I have version 11.0.0.0. from July '16.- I'll update, just in case.

Comment: It works just fine in 10.4.1 and 11.0.1. It appears that JoinAcross has problems in 11.0.0 (Win 7, 64-bit).

Comment: Yes, @WReach I can confirm this. I just installed 11.0.1 on Win10/64bit and it works fine.

Comment: @niloderoock read it over, let me know if it could use anymore editing.

Comment: JoinAcross works really, really well in 11.0.1.0.